# How do I map numbers, non-linearly, between 0 and a uncertain large number to go between 0 and 1

Tags: math

I want to map numbers between 0 and m to go between 0 and 1, but m is uncertain and approximately large number. How do I map this numbers, non-linearly, between 0 and an uncertain large number to go between 0 and 1. I used arctan function but it's not very good and uniform.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you would like the results to be?  Are you mapping 1 number at a time, or a range of numbers?

Comment: Are there requirements for monotonicity, continuity, etc. If not, then `sin`, `cos`, `1.0 / (x + 1)`, `x / (x + k)`, `(x mod n) / n`, and so many others all map `[0, m] -> [0, 1]`. It might help if you can give a little more detailed specification of the requirements...

Comment: Off topic, this is maths not programming.

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you want a non-linear function to map an arbitrary domain of positive real numbers to a codomain of real numbers [0,1], then you could theoretically use:

```
f(x) = x / (x + 1)
```

This function is continuous at all points [0,infinity).

However, you have to realize that floating point numbers are limited in bits. At some point, there will be collisions depending on the implementation.